# How to check if DateTime Value is before a specific DateTime in LINQ

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this LINQ query :

```
var post = _db.Posts.Where(m => m.CreateDate < **13.12.2016 Hour : 18:30**)
```

I don't know how to set the DateTime there. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: **13.12.2016 Hour : 18:30** is that your datetime you want to compare ?

Comment: @BharatPatidar Yes, I want to get records before that DateTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct DateTime object with the date you have. You can do it in one of the following ways.

One way of doing it is..

```
var post = _db.Posts.Where(m => m.CreateDate < (new DateTime(2016,12,13,18,30,0)))
```

Another way is

```
var post = _db.Posts.Where(m => m.CreateDate < DateTime.Parse("13/12/2016 18:30"))
```

Comment: @jason:Yes, it is!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the constructor of the DateTime class to build the required date by specifying the values(`year,month,day,hour,minute,second`), then use that datetime-Object in your Linq query for performing the comparison. which will give you the expected result:

Try this :

```
 DateTime limitDate = new DateTime(2016, 12, 13, 18, 30, 00);
 var post = _db.Posts.Where(m => m.CreateDate < limitDate);
```

Or else you can create the DateTimeObject by parsing some string inputs that's your Datelimit